Scrollview Nested Multi Flashlist Scroll Abnormal React Native
Here is my code where ScrollView two FlashList nested，

if i do not limit FlashList height，it will render all items at first time。

if i use a view element to wrap them，The scrolling will stop when the first list scroll to the bottom.

Demo: https://github.com/vanBlayt/rn-flashlist-demo


      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        scrollEnabled={outerScrollEnable}
        nestedScrollEnabled
        ref={scrollViewRef}
      >
        <View style={{ height: height, backgroundColor: "#333" }}>
          <FlashList
            data={list}
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            estimatedItemSize={68}
            // style={{ flex: 1 }}
            scrollEnabled={goodsScrollEnable}
            nestedScrollEnabled
            onEndReached={handleGoodsEndReached}
            renderScrollComponent={renderScrollComponent}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ height, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
          <FlashList
            data={list2}
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            estimatedItemSize={68}
            // style={{ flex: 1 }}
            scrollEnabled={recommendScrollEnable}
            nestedScrollEnabled
            renderScrollComponent={renderScrollComponent}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>

Expected Results

all items are rendered lazily
Scrolling is smooth and coherent

